# Please tell me if i can select the below mentioned elements using a single jquery statement

Tags: jquery, html

Say we have a div named 'slide_down_div' that contains two ul(lists). And I want to make the following selections:

1. `$('#slide_down_div ul:eq(0)');`   and the second one..
2. `$('#slide_down_div ul:eq(1)');`    i want your help on this one

Now, in the 2nd statement I further want to select the 1st and the 5th li(list item) so as to apply some style to them... Is there a way? Please suggest.

Further, please tell me if I can merge the above two jquery statements into a single one.

```
<ul>
    <li><img src='images/WindowsLogo.png'/>Windows</li>
    <li><img src='images/OfficeLogo.png'/>Office</li>
    <li><img src='images/OfficeLogo.png'/>Xbox</li>
    <li><img src='images/PhoneLogo.png'/>Windows Phone</li> 
    <li><img src='images/IELogo.png'/>Internet Explorer</li>
    <li><img src='images/logo_skype.png'/>Skype</li>
</ul>   

<ul>
    <li>For Home</li>
    <li>Security Essentials</li>
    <li>Microsoft Update</li>
    <li>PC Hardware</li>
    <li>PC Gaming</li>
    <li>For Work</li>
    <li>Small &amp; Medium Businesses</li>
    <li>IT Specialist Locator</li>
    <li>Enterprise</li>
    <li>Server &amp; Tools</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a single statement that selects three elements: (1) the first ul, (2) the second ul's 1st li, (3) the second ul's 5th li?

Comment: Please use proper english here, i.e. no "4 ur" instead of "for your" etc.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Come on buddy,i am not using something offensive.Just shortcuts which i think are well understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the the two first `li` elements in the first `ul` :

```
var first = $("#slide_down_div ul:eq(0) li:lt(2)")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
```

Get the first and fifth `li` elements in the second `ul` :

```
var second = $("li:eq(0), li:eq(4)", "#slide_down_div ul:eq(1)");
```

Join both together to one selector

```
var both = first.add(second);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AmPN9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var $first = $('#slide_down_div ul:first'); 
var $second = $('#slide_down_div ul:eq(1)');
$second.find('li:eq(0), li:eq(4)').foo()
```

```
var $both = $('#slide_down_div').find('ul:first, ul:eq(1)')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7SjLE/1/)

`:lt()` selector:

```
var $both = $('#slide_down_div ul:lt(2)')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7SjLE/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to add CSS class for first and last `<li/>` for every `<ul/>`?

```
<div id="slide_down_div">
    <ul class="test">
        ...
    </ul>
    <ul class="test">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#slide_down_div').find('ul.test').each(function () {
            $(this).find('li:eq(0), li:eq(4)').addClass('TestClass');
            //Or
            $(this).find('li:first, li:last').addClass('TestClass');
        });
    });
</script>
```